# Camping around Toronto, Ontario for the new year weekend

Tags: canada, camping, outdoor-activities, toronto, ontario

I live in Toronto by the lakeshore. I had a long yearning to spend new years eve by myself out in the middle of nowhere, under the stars, in a tent.
Now I have 3 days off - 31st Dec, 1st Jan and 2nd Jan.

Where can I go for a nice solo camping trip? Not too difficult since my camping level is beginner. All I plan to do is hike a bit and basically stay inside and read or something. No fishing/hunting/skiing.

Because of the weather, maybe living in a tent is not a good idea, so any small private lodges (cheap) are a welcome option too.
I just don't want to end up sitting in my condo and going out to a pub to celebrate 31st.

Comment: Please, don't use so many `.` in your questions.

Comment: A beginner should not winter camp in Southern Ontario.

Comment: Not necessarily camping in the usual way, but if you're around Toronto, I'd recommend going to Queen Victoria Park in Niagara Falls, Ontario, for the New Year's Eve concert, which they have every year, with free admission. http://www.niagaraparks.com/niagara-falls-events/new-years-eve-niagara-falls.html I went on 2008-12-31 for Roger Hodgson of Supertramp, and on 2009-12-31 for Styx. It's a great show, and it's free (unless you come too late, and can't find any free parking). There are lots of people attending from Toronto.

Comment: See also [Outdoors.SE].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a recollection of taking a trip (some decades ago) between the Niagara Falls and Toronto, and seeing a number of farms along the way. In your shoes, I might take that route during the fall, and talk to some farmers, and see what they have to say about lodges.

If all else fails, I'd think about spending the vacation in someone's farmhouse or barn. Maybe you'd end up "housesitting" for someone who wants to head south, or trade places with you for an urban setting.

Comment: When you say 'take the trip', you mean by foot? Or you drove and stopped along on farm houses?

Comment: @Kaushik: I meant driving, and stopping by farm houses. In my case, I was 14 at the time, so my father drove. Thanks for your interest and votes.

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for something that is a bit more outdoorsy than a 'private lodge', then may I suggest a yurt? These are wooden huts, usually designed for six or eight and with a stove, perfectly suited to winter camping. There are yurts at Mew Lake campground in Algonquin Park, The Pinery on Lake Huron, and Killarney - all several hours from Toronto.

- [The Pinery](http://www.ontarioparks.com/english/pineryyurts.html)
- [Killarney](http://www.ontariooutdoor.com/details.aspx?pkgid=631&gid=p33&aid=p58&sid=0&cid=0&language=en)
- [Algonquin](http://www.ontarioparks.com/english/algo-winter.html)

All of these places have real winter camping as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have already googled, but maybe this site can help you:

http://www.cottage-resort.com/

However the site looks really weird, but I think to get some information it is okay.

Answer (score 1):

I used to live in a town called Penetanguishene, Ontario. This is about 1 hour and 45 minutes away from toronto. There; There is a beautiful, easy going, campground called Awenda Provincial Park. It's a great place to go camping by yourself. The link below is where it is on google maps.

https://maps.google.com.au/maps?client=safari&q=Awenda+Park+Ontario+map&ie=UTF-8&ei=kmXBUp3LB6WQiAfohIC4DA&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAg

Also, if you want an even more beautiful place, thats away from everything, (if you have your own boat or canoe, or willing to rent one) there is an amazing place to camp called Massasauga Provincial Park. It's about an hour north of Penetanguishene The most amazing times I have ever gone camping were here. The link below is where it is on google maps.

https://maps.google.com.au/maps?client=safari&q=Massasauga+Provincial+Park+Map&ie=UTF-8&ei=GGXBUrzEG6XoiAfa-YGwDA&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAg

Comment: I did just realise my stupidity, because I'm in Australia, I was answering as if it was summer. I don't think it would be as beautiful in a tent as I was saying... And forget about renting that boat...

But either way, those places are amazing in the summer :P